# TYPO3 footer menu

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I wonder what is the best way to do this.
I have two menues on the template for the first two levels of the navigation. They are separate, because they are on slightly different locations on the page.

Now, I used to put all my special `meta-nav` and `footer` pages into a `sysfolder`. That actually works pretty fine with `special.directory`. So far all good.

But when I open a link from the `footer`, the `footer menu's` links are shown in the 2nd-level `HMENU`. It makes more or less sense as the pages are in a `sub-folder` and therefore 2nd-level. , but they are in a folder.. So I guessed it should work.

My solution is to hide all pages in the `sys-folder` and in the `footer menu` using `includeNotInMenu`. That works, but I wonder if there is a cleaner solution to avoid sys-folder's content to be treated as 2nd-level pages. I don't like the editor to have to remember to hide the pages to get the expected result.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are asking for "hide in menus". Edit your page sitemap, go to tab "access" select "hide" below "In Menus". Sitemap will not be shown in your menu, as long as you do not set "includeNotInMenu" in your menu rendering.

```
# assume 12 is the uid of your folder
[PIDinRootline = 12]
  # Delete the menu
  lib.yourmenu >
  # or overwrite it:
  lib.yourmenu = TEXT
  lib.yourmenu.value = there is nothing to see here
[end]
```

Using conditions is more difficult to debug. You need to select them in TypoScript Object-Browser, if you want to see the effect of an condition.

Comment: Yes thank you, this is what I am currently doing. If this is the way to do it: perfect. :) I'm just not 100% happy as the user needs to remember to hide the page.

Comment: you can use conditions as well. There are different ways to do, everyone has pro and con.

Comment: Thank you, the idea with conditions is great. I wan't the easiest setup for the editors.

Answer (score 0):

You can sent an `entryLevel`

> Defines at which level in the rootLine, the menu should start. Default
>   is "0" which gives us a menu of the very first pages on the site.
>
> If the value is < 0, entryLevel is chosen from "behind" in the
>   rootLine. Thus "-1" is a menu with items from the outermost level,
>   "-2" is the level before the outermost...

See http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/HMENU

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.. Assume I have the following structure

- home
- home/subpage1
- home/subpage2
- meta-nav
- meta-nav/sitemap
- meta-nav/impressum

-> `meta-nav` is a folder.

Now I have a `HMENU` for the 2nd level and it shows (depending on the selected page):

```
(subpage1 and subpage2) or (sitemap and impressum)
```

Now what I want to achieve is to open the `sitemap` or the `impressum` and not see those in the `HMENU`.

Sorry if that all sounds strange ;-)